# Cant align an image center relative to the textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Hi, I have two text view and one image view inside a relative layout,
 **I want to align image view centre according to textview** parallel, but
   now  imagview aligning down parallel to text view, pls help me.i want result 
   as 1st image,but now am getting like second image

```
<LinearLayout

android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totPendingTxt"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="TOTAL"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/Color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
        android:id="@+id/imgPendingOrder"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/totPendingTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_arrow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalPendingOrders"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/Color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />


</RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with my following code,may b it will help you:)

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totPendingTxt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:text="TOTAL"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                     android:textColor="@color/Color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgPendingOrder"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_arrow" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totalPendingOrders"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textAllCaps="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```